# RequireJS and Breeze not playing nicely

Tags: javascript, requirejs, breeze, durandal

**Problem:**

RequireJS does not seem to be playing nicely with Breeze.

I have an error as follows:

```
Unable to initialize OData.  Needed to support remote OData services
```

This generally means that **datajs** is not loaded and needs to be added to the page before **breeze**. However, I have done this with **RequireJS** - or at least I think I have, but may have something wrong or missing in my config.

**My Config:**

**main.js** contains the following:

```
var paths = {
    'text': '../text',
    'durandal': '../durandal',
    'plugins': '../durandal/plugins',
    'transitions': '../durandal/transitions',
    'breeze': '../breeze.debug',
    'datajs': '../datajs-1.1.3',
    'q': '../q',
};

var shim = {
    'datajs': ['jquery'],
    'breeze': ['jquery', 'datajs', 'q']
};

requirejs.config({
    paths: paths,
    shim: shim
});
```

Test module (a very simple test page), as follows:

**JS:**

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'datajs', 'q', 'breeze'], function ($, ko, datajs, q, breeze) {
    return {
        people: ko.observableArray([]),

        attached: function () {
            breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
            var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/odata');

            var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
                .from("People")
                .orderBy("Name asc");

            manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
                this.people([]);

                $(data.httpResponse.data.results).each(function () {
                    var current = this;
                    this.people.push({ Id: current.Id, Name: current.Name });
                });
            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

As you can see, I have specified **datajs** and **q** as dependencies of **breeze**. So, what am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I inspected the HTML via FireBug and as you can see, both **q** and **datajs** seem to be loaded before **breeze**. So I am totally confused here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer here:
[DataJS library not loading in RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842892/datajs-library-not-loading-in-requirejs)

Apparently, we need to reference 2 separate objects for the same **js** file... as follows:

```
'paths': {
    'datajs': '../datajs-1.1.3',
    'OData': '../datajs-1.1.3',
},
'shim': {
    'OData':['datajs']
}
```